# Python cannont import own poetry package: ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-packaging, python-poetry

I wrote a python package tu bundle some math and plotting functions. I've built it with poetry.

Unfortunately, I cannot import it. There are some issues with `pip install` (`ResolutionError`) as well eg when installing from own devpi repo, but thats not the major issue here.

When I get the package installed, I still cannot use it: `ModuleNotFoundError`.
I was able to reproduce a MWE on base of [`sampleproject`](https://stackoverflow.com):

```
 |-LICENSE.txt
 |-dist
 | |-sampleproject-3.0.0.tar.gz
 | |-sampleproject-3.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
 |-pyproject.toml.template
 |-README.md
 |-.github
 | |-workflows
 | | |-release.yml
 | | |-test.yml
 |-tox.ini
 |-.gitignore
 |-pyproject.toml
 |-src
 | |-sample
 | | |-__init__.py
 | | |-package_data.dat
 | | |-simple.py
 |-tests
 | |-__init__.py
 | |-test_simple.py
```

The `__init__.py` file is empty. Is that right?
Modified `pyproject.toml` for poetry:

```ini
[tool.poetry]
name = "sampleproject"  # Required
version = "3.0.0"  # Required
description = "A sample Python project"  # Optional
readme = "README.md" # Optional
license = "LICENSE"
keywords = ["sample", "setuptools", "development"]  # Optional
authors = ["A. Random Developer <author@example.com>"] # Optional
packages = [{include="src/sample"}]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = ">=3.7"

[project.scripts]  # Optional
sample = "sample:main"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.6.1"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

And the result:

```
>>> import sampleproject
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sampleproject'
```

I am using:
`python` in different versions with `miniconda` in WSL Debian 11 und Ubuntu 22.

Anyone has a guess what is going wrong here?
Thanks already :)

PS: I checked with `pip list` or `pip freeze` that the package is installed. So I should try to use it in the right environment. The mistake has to be somewhere else...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```ini
packages = [{include="src/sample"}]
```

to

```ini
packages = [{ from = "src", include="sample" }]
```

Then, import `sample` as

```
>>> import sample
```

Note that `sample` is the name of the [import package](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/glossary/#term-Import-Package), which comes from the name of the actual source directory and is what ends up on the Python path, while `sampleproject` is the name of the [distribution package](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/glossary/#term-Distribution-Package), which is what you set in your build system metadata.